# count the subdocument field and total amount in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've a collection with below documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54acfb67a81bf9509246ed81"),
    "Billno" : 1234,
    "details" : [ 
        {
            "itemcode" : 12,
            "itemname" : "Paste100g",
            "qty" : 2,
            "price" : 50
        }, 
        {
            "itemcode" : 14,
            "itemname" : "Paste30g",
            "qty" : 4,
            "price" : 70
        }, 
        {
            "itemcode" : 12,
            "itemname" : "Paste100g",
            "qty" : 4,
            "price" : 100
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54acff86a81bf9509246ed82"),
    "Billno" : 1237,
    "details" : [ 
        {
            "itemcode" : 12,
            "itemname" : "Paste100g",
            "qty" : 3,
            "price" : 75
        }, 
        {
            "itemcode" : 19,
            "itemname" : "dates100g",
            "qty" : 4,
            "price" : 170
        }, 
        {
            "itemcode" : 22,
            "itemname" : "dates200g",
            "qty" : 2,
            "price" : 160
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to display below output. Please help

Required Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
itemcode           itemname               totalprice       totalqty
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
12                 Paste100g               225                9
14                 Paste30g                 70                4
19                 dates100g               170                4
22                 dates200g               160                2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MongoDB [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is available to solve your problem. You get details out of an array my processing with [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then using [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to "sum" the totals:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array to de-normalize as documents
    { "$unwind": "$details" },

    // Group on the key you want and provide other values
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$details.itemcode",
        "itemname": { "$first": "$details.itemname" },
        "totalprice": { "$sum": "$details.price" },
        "totalqty": { "$sum": "$details.qty" }
    }}
])
```

Ideally you want a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage in there to filter out any irrelevant data first. This is basically MongoDB query and takes all the same arguments and operators.

Most here is simple really. The [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is sort of like a "JOIN" in SQL except that in an embedded structure the "join" is already made, so you are just "de-normalizing" like a join would do between "one to many" table relationships but just within the document itself. It basically "repeats" the "parent" document parts to the array for each array member as a new document.

Then the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) works of a key, as in "GROUP BY", where the "key" is the `_id` value. Everything there is "distinct" and all other values are gathered by "grouping operators".

This is where operations like [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) come in. As described on the manual page, this takes the "first" value from the "grouping boundary" mentioned in the "key" earlier. You want this because all values of this field are "likely" to be the same, so this is a logical choice to just pick the "first" match.

Finally there is the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) grouping operator which does what should be expected. All supplied values under the "key" are "added" or "summed" together to provide a total. Just like SQL `SUM()`.

Also note that all the `$` prefixed names there is how the aggregation framework deals with variables for "field/property" names within the current document being processed. ["Dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) is used to reference the embedded "fields/properties" nested within a parent property name.

It is useful to learn aggregation in MongoDB. It is to general queries what anything beyond a basic "SELECT" statement is to SQL. Not just for "grouping" but for other manipulation as well.

Read through the documentation of all [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and also take a look a [SQL to Aggregation Mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the documentation as a general guide if you have some familiarity with SQL to begin with. It helps explain concepts and shows some things that can be done.

Comment: @Disposer I should hire you as my personal editor. It was intended as a "newbie" reference, so I have added that and other missing information. I should blog more really, and I did write more for MongoDB official documentation as well, but that disappeared when someone decided that interns would provide examples in the sections. Don't know what happened about that. Thanks for the insight. It makes the response better.

Comment: Thanks you. suppose I've to display the details from main document (Billno in this case).How can i display the Billno agaist each result set.

Comment: @Roots Since you are grouping across documents then anything unique to a document would not have a distinct value matching your grouping key. You could either use `$first` to get the "first" occurrence or `$push` to form an array, or any other grouping operator. If you are unable to work that out, then it is best to ask another question that clearly describes your desired result. The listing here produces your desired output as asked from your data sample provided.