# mongodb get count of nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is my mongodb document where values contains HOUR -> MINUTES -> KEY = VALUE

```
  {"_id" : 100,
"timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
"values" : {
    "13" : {
        "15" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "16" : { "0" : "sam", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "17" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "18" : { "0" : "sam", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "19" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "20" : { "0" : "sam", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "21" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"}
    },
    "14" : {
        "15" : { "0" : "sam", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "16" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "17" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "18" : { "0" : "sam", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "19" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "20" : { "0" : "sam", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"},
        "21" : { "0" : "bob", "1" : "bob", "2": "sam"}
    },
}
```

expected output 
Count of "bob" in grouped by hour, minute

Comment: take a look at this. It will guide you achieve what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820596/count-the-subdocument-field-and-total-amount-in-mongodb

Comment: they use $unwind function but my document contains only nested object  not array